# Remove a subview from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I'm adding a subview to the main view but then I cant remove it from this view.

```
NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init];

nextView.transitioningDelegate = self;
nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.presentedViewController.view addSubview:nextView.view];
nextView.view.frame = CGRectMake(724, 80, 300, 150);

UIButton *stayButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(101, 94, 90, 49)];
[stayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stayButton setTitle:@"Detener" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stayButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(waitForNextView)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nextView.view addSubview:stayButton];
stayButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
[stayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

here I'm adding a button to the view and then when the button is pushed it goes`-

```
(void)waitForNextView{
    transition = NO;
    NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
    SectionViewController *sectionView = [[SectionViewController alloc]init];
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    actualSection = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(dismissView2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I've tried with:

`[nextView.view removeFromSuperView];`

`[nextView.presentedViewController removeFromParentViewController];`

But I don't know what else can I do :S

If you want more information, nextView is a UIViewController of 300x100 size. I want to present it and then remove it when I hit the button, that's all.

I would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Post the dissmissView2 method where you are trying to call [nextView.view removeFromSuperView];

Comment: Which view do you want to remove? Is it the button or do you want to remove NextView? If NextView is a UIViewController subclass, to dismiss it use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating different reference and then you're trying to remove it from its superview while not being added at all. I will try to explain:
1. When you're adding `nextView.view` to `self.view` you have created a instance like this

```
NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
```

2. When you're trying to remove it, instead of referring to the instance above you're creating a brand new one again in your `waitForNextView` method like so again

```
 NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
```

and then you're trying to remove it. Please note that the last instance of `nextView` has not being added anywhere yet, and this is the reason your code doesn't work.

In order to work you should refer to the first reference you've added to `self.view`. Please adjust your code as shown below

In your `ViewController.m`

```
@interface ViewController()
{
 NextViewController *nextView;
}
```

When adding your `viewController`

```
nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init];

nextView.transitioningDelegate = self;
nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.presentedViewController.view addSubview:nextView.view];
nextView.view.frame = CGRectMake(724, 80, 300, 150);

UIButton *stayButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(101, 94, 90, 49)];
[stayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stayButton setTitle:@"Detener" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stayButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(waitForNextView)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nextView.view addSubview:stayButton];
stayButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
[stayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And finally in your `IBAction` method

```
-(void)waitForNextView{
    transition = NO;
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    actualSection = 0;
    [nextView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly but i've changed `[nextView removeFromSuperview];`
for `[nextView.view removeFromSuperView];
Thanks so much Panayot, u've saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are adding the button as a subview to the view of nextView, so removing the view of nextView won't work.

If you add a tag to your button, then you can retrieve the subview by using the tag. Eg. When you define your button:

```
[stayButton setTag:1];
```

Then in the `waitForNextView` method, you can get the control like this:

```
UIButton *stayButton = (UIButton*)[nextView.view viewWithTag:1];
[stayButton removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in the methode  dismissView2

```
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews ){
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```